# After clicking a button control need to go to another button in the same view controller, but causing the error

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with swift and my problem is when i clicked on a button the control needs to go to another button in the same viewcontroller. But I am facing the following error. Please let me know the solution.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'GameViewController.xib''

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add GameViewController.xib to your target (Targets -> Build Phases - > Copy Bundle Resources)